# Problem to instal INTL extension on php 7.3 in MAC 10.14

Tags: php, macos, int

I am configuring local cakephp 3, but I am not able to install ext intl on mac, I have the following error when trying:

```
1 error generated.
make: *** [php_intl.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make 'failed
```

this error occurs when executing the following command:
sudo pecl install intl

Can someone help me with this? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many time later, i finally fix it:

First make sure you installed Xcode and started it at least once to finish installation and accept license agreement.

Download latest version of autoconf from

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/autoconf/autoconf-latest.tar.gz.

Its a prerequisite to build php modules which is not shipped with macOS.
Extract the file and open a terminal in macOS and open the extracted folder using cd command.

Afterwards use commands:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install (your password is required, make sure you are an admin user in macOS)
```

Download the version of php you use in xampp from php.net

Extract it and open the extracted folder in a terminal using cd.
Change to subfolder ext/intl.

Run these commands to build the extension:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/phpize

./configure --enable-intl --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/bin/php-config --with-icu-dir=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/

make

sudo make install (password required)
```

Delete all files you downloaded and also the extracted folders.
Add to php.ini file in xampp/etc folder line 
extension="intl.so"

Since intl-extension has to be compiled anew each time you installed a new version of xampp I wrote a shell script to do this for me.

Comment: this, this is the only way i managed to get the intl.so